# Como hacer que una función espere a otra para ejecutarse en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy intententando hacer un formulario dinamico en React con usuarios de una api, pero no se como hacer para que la funcion que renderiza la lista de los usuarios espere la respuesta de la api, lo he intentado hacer con el estado pero este obviamente me lee el estado inicial el cual he declarado como nulo y con setState he intentado cambiarlo sin exito.

Aqui el codigo.

```
const [usuarios, setUsuarios] = React.useState(null) 

React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(resp => {
               setUsuarios(resp.data)
            })
    }, []);

const Opciones = () => {
        
    return (
          
     <Form.Control as="select" aria-label="Default select example" onChange={handleChangePerson}>
     {usuarios.map(({id}) => (
       <React.Fragment key={id}>
           <option>Seleccione una opcion</option>
           <option value="1">{id}</option>
       </React.Fragment>
                ))}
     </Form.Control>
          
      );
    }
```

**Asi luce, donde dice selecciona una opcion es que se va a renderizar los nombres que traiga de la api.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes agregar el código completo del componente?

Comment: Yo es que ente caso, lo que haría, sería  meter el renderizado en un if que comprobara que usuarios != null && usuarios.length > 0. Así no te mostraría nada hasta que tuviese elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo que estas intentando es [Renderizado condicional](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html), el cual se puede realizar de varias maneras, desde diseñar un componente especifico, hasta usar [Operador condicional ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Para este ejemplo lo aremos utilizando `if`.

1. Primero inicializa tu `useState` como un arreglo vació:

   ```
   const [usuarios, setUsuarios] = React.useState([])
   ```
2. Ahora con eso podemos comprobar si hay elementos en tu arreglo dentro de nuestro Elemento que vamos a renderizar en caso de no haber elementos solo mostraremos un `div` con un pequeño texto.

   ```
    const ElementConditional = () => {
        if (data.length === 0) {
            return <div>Cargando datos...</div>
        }
        return (
            <select>
                <option>Seleccione una opcion</option>
                {data.map(({ id }) => (<option value={id} key={id}>{id}</option>))}
            </select>
        );
    }
   ```

---

Al final tu Código podría quedar de la siguiente manera.

```
const [usuarios, setUsuarios] = React.useState([])

React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(resp => {
            setUsuarios(resp.data)
        })
}, []);

const ElementConditional = () => {
    if (data.length === 0) {
        return <div>Cargando datos...</div>
    }
    return (
        <select>
            <option>Seleccione una opcion</option>
            {data.map(({ id }) => (<option value={id} key={id}>{id}</option>))}
        </select>
    );
}

const Opciones = () => {

    return (

        <Form.Control as="select" aria-label="Default select example" onChange={handleChangePerson}>
            <ElementConditional />
        </Form.Control>

    );
}
```